# 3D Plot with the Manipulate Command

Tags: plotting, manipulate, graphics3d

I'm trying to make a 3D Plot using the Manipulate command. The code is:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

G = 0.01;
β = 1;
ωc = 50;
J = 1;
ϕ = 0;
θ = π/2;
η = Exp[I ϕ]*Tan[θ/2];

integralgamma[ω_, τ_] := 
  4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((1 - 
    Cos[ω τ])/ω^(2)) Coth[β ω/2]; 

integraldelta[ω_, τ_] := 
 4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] (Sin[ω τ] - \
  ω τ)/ω^2;

ψ = Exp[I α] * Tan[χ/2];

old[τ_] :=    (Abs[η]/(1 + Abs[η]^2) )^(4 J) * 
 Sum[Binomial[2 J, J + m] * Binomial[2 J, J + p] * 
  Abs[η]^(2 m + 2 p) * 
   Exp[-NIntegrate[
    integralgamma[ω, τ], {ω, 0, 70000}, 
     Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15]* (m - p)^2] * 
      Exp[- I * 
       NIntegrate[
        integraldelta[ω, τ], {ω, 0, 70000}, 
         Method -> "LocalAdaptive", 
          MaxRecursion -> 15]* (m^2 - p^2)]  , {m, -1, 1, 1}, {p, -1, 
           1, 1}];

new[\[Alpha]_, \[Chi]_, \[Tau]_] := (Abs[ψ]/(1 + 
 Abs[ψ]^2) )^(2 J)*(Abs[η]/(1 + 
  Abs[η]^2) )^(2 J) * 
   Sum[Binomial[2 J, J + m] * Binomial[2 J, J + p] * 
    Abs[ψ]^(2 m + 2 p) * Abs[η]^(2 m + 2 p) * 
     Exp[-NIntegrate[
      integralgamma[ω, τ], {ω, 0, 70000}, 
       Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15]* (m - p)^2] * 
        Exp[- I * 
         NIntegrate[
          integraldelta[ω, τ], {ω, 0, 70000}, 
           Method -> "LocalAdaptive", 
            MaxRecursion -> 15]* (m^2 - p^2)]  , {m, -1, 1, 1}, {p, -1, 
             1, 1}];

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[new[\[Alpha], \[Chi], \[Tau]]] - 
  Evaluate[old[\[Tau]]], {\[Alpha], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Chi], 
   0, \[Pi]}], {\[Tau], 0, 1}]
```

I get the result:

[image]

Help, please. Thanks.

Comment: Remove the underscores from `new[...]` and `old[...]` in your plot to start

Comment: Rendering any `Plot3D[]` will take a long time here, `Manipulate[]` isn't the way to go.

Comment: @J_Nat Edited. Check the code. I get a similar error. See the edited post.

Comment: @Feyre Any suggestions?

Comment: I got no errors, just `$Aborted` in place of the plot which backs up Feyre's comment that it takes too long in the current state.

Comment: For one, How come the function `new[]` is independent of `alpha`? Any `Table[]` I run seems to confirm that.

Comment: @Feyre `New[]` is not independent of it? The parenthesis clearly has an alpha in it.

Comment: @J_Nat and others: Hmm. Any alternative computational suggestions then?

Comment: Another thing, your `\[Tau], \[Alpha], and \[Chi]` are in different order from when you define it and when you use it in `Manipulate`. Not sure if that was intentional or not...

Comment: @J_Nat and others: Edited the code and the question. I now only get the error `Aborted.` Suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, of course. Silly typos. It'd be great if you could address the larger problem: aborted; it seems the computation is too long!

Comment: `ψ` should be defined as a function with parameters `α` and `χ`: `ψ[α_, χ_] := Exp[I α] * Tan[χ/2]` (and change all references to `ψ` to `ψ[α, χ]`.  I believe you've been advised before (by J.M.) to use the interval `{ω, 0, Infinity}` -- much better than approximating infinity with 70000.  Lower the precision goal to an appropriate setting for plotting, say, `PrecisionGoal -> 3` or `4`.  And drop the `"LocalAdaptive"` until you're sure it is needed: it tends to be slow, which leads to violating the dynamic updating time limit (5-6 sec.), which leads to `$Aborted`.

Comment: That said, you're calculating 4 numerical integrals for each point calculated by `Plot3D`. I'll be surprised if the tips I gave make it fast enough to avoid `$Aborted`. There's a lot to do, it seems to me, for you to make this work.  You might be thinking about alternate strategies to achieve your ultimate goal (i.e., why you are doing this). There may be a better way.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes. I posted a question about it (general strategy etc.) but it wasn't well received. Can we continue this discussion in chat?

Comment: Finally, if you wish to persist with `Manipulate`, you can try adding the option `SynchronousUpdating -> False`.  (But you should read up on how it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42855/discussion-between-junaid-aftab-and-michael-e2).

Comment: @MichaelE2 See the chat for this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** using `mem:` as suggested by Simon Woods.

Perhaps using [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html) at a couple of intervals of tau will be enlightening. The results seems plausible based on the fact that `old` is a 1D function.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

G = 0.01;
β = 1;
ωc = 50;
j = 1;
ϕ = 0;
θ = π/2;

η = Exp[I ϕ] Tan[θ/2];

Clear[ψ]
ψ[α_, χ_] := Exp[I α]*Tan[χ/2];

integralgamma[ω_, τ_] := 4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((1 - Cos[ω τ])/ω^(2)) Coth[β ω/2] 
integraldelta[ω_, τ_] := 4 G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] (Sin[ω τ] - ω τ)/ω^2

mem :δ[τ_]:= mem=NIntegrate[integraldelta[ω, τ], {ω, 0, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 3]
mem :γ[τ_]:= mem=NIntegrate[integralgamma[ω, τ], {ω, 0, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 3]

old[τ_] := -(1/τ) Log[
  (Abs[η]/(1 + Abs[η]^2))^(4 j) 
   Sum[Abs[η]^(2 m + 2 p) 
   Binomial[2 j, j + m] Binomial[2 j, j + p] 
   Exp[-I δ[τ] (m^2 - p^2)] Exp[-γ[τ] (m - p)^2], 
   {m, -j, j, 1}, {p, -j, j, 1}]]

new[α_, χ_, τ_] := -(1/τ) Log[
 (Abs[ψ[α, χ]]/(1 + Abs[ψ[α, χ]]^2))^(4 j)  (Abs[η]/(1 + Abs[η]^2))^(2 j)
  Sum[Abs[η]^(2 m + 2 p) Abs[ψ[α, χ]]^(2 m + 2 p) 
  Binomial[2 j, j + m] Binomial[2 j,j + p] 
  Exp[-I δ[τ] (m^2 - p^2)] Exp[-γ[τ] (m - p)^2], 
  {m, -j, j, 1}, {p, -j, j, 1}]]
```

Table Plots:

```
Table[Plot3D[
  Re[new[α, χ, τ] - old[τ]], {α, 0, 2 π}, {χ, 0, π}, 
   PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 0,
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#3, {-2, 8}]] &),
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> {-2, 8}], {τ, 0.2, 2.0, 0.1}]
```

[image]

$j=2$

[image]

Comment: What about the other graphs for the other times, tau? I'm assuming this graph is for one fixed time, tau. Also, why are there two branches/surfaces in the graph. I want to calculate the difference of the two functions -- so shouldn't there be one surface?

Comment: I ran the command with `{\[Tau], 0.5, 1}.` I got one graph. Shouldn't I be getting two graphs -- one that computes the difference, `new - old`, for `\[Tau] = 0.5` and the other that does the same for `\[Tau] = 1`?

Comment: @JunaidAftab As you can see here, `alpha` does nog affect the graph.

Comment: @Feyre I'm not sure what's on the axes then - Cho which is till 2pi. What about the other axes? I expect the axes representing the difference to be between - 1 and 1. :/

Comment: You can see from the fact he is using `{α, 0, 2 π}, {χ, 0, π}`. The `z` axis is the value for the functions of two different values of `τ`.

Comment: @Feyre So if I plot this graph for 3 values of tau, shouldn't I get three different surfaces: with alpha and chi on the horizontal axes, new - old on the vertical axis -- and the number of surfaces correspond to the number of different tau which I specified in the relevant list in the code.

Comment: Yound and @Feyre, I am getting very weird and different results with this approach. Can you help me out? I don't see any option of chatting this thread out. Please do that and come over there. Thanks.

Comment: May I suggest that you memoize both the numerical integrations, e.g. `mem:δ[τ_] := mem = NIntegrate[...]`. The same integration is performed multiple times so this will save a lot of time.

Comment: @SimonWoods Awesome suggestion.

Comment: @SimonWoods Awesome suggestion. It has significantly reduced the time it take to do all the computations -- for example, I wanted to take 10 graphs using the `Table` command. While previously it took me about 30-40 minutes to do this, it now takes me less than a minute or two to get the required output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way of plotting 4d data is with:

```
DensityPlot3D[
 Re[new[α, χ, τ] - old[τ]], {χ, 
  0, π}, {α, 0, 2 π}, {τ, 0.1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 11]
```

[image]

To do this with manipulate, it is wise to do all the calculations first, and storing the values in a dataset.

```
data = Table[
   Table[{α, χ, 
     Re[new[α, χ, τ] - old[τ]]}, {χ, π/
      16, π, π/8}, {α, 0, 2 π, π/4}], {τ, 
    0.1, 1, 0.1}];
```

This creates a file for values and coordinates `α, χ`. Note, this takes a while to create.

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot3D[Flatten[data[[τ, All, All, All]], 1]], {τ, 1, 
  Length[data[[All, 1, 1, 1]]], 1}]
```

This plots the data where you can change `τ` like you requested as a `Manipulate[]`

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the interpretation of this graph? I'm looking at it for the first time. I can identify which axis is which -- and the difference between new and old is between 0 and 1 so that's good.

Comment: @JunaidAftab This is a Densityplot, that means every point in the space here has a value, this is the value of the function `new[α, χ, τ] - old[τ]` at the triplet `{χ,α,τ}`

Comment: So the axes represent chi and alpha. At each point, what is the value of tau? I don't get it. Also, at each triplet, how do I interpret the value of new - old? What do the different colours in the plot represent?

Comment: In this case `τ` is the vertical-axis. You can add `, PlotLegends -> Automatic` to show a numerical value for the various colours.
I can think of one way to actually plot this in the original way you intended, I'll add it soon.

Comment: So the horizontal axes represent chi and alpha and the veto ticks axis represents tau. My question still is: 1) how is tau modelled in the graph? Is tau discrete or does it take a continuum of values between 0 and 1? 2) how do I interpret the value of new - old at each triplet -- what do the colours represent?

Comment: @JunaidAftab Tau is the vertical axis in that plot, between 0 and 1. The colour of the plot changes with the value of the function.
But I think my second code is what you were after.

Comment: I get all sorts of errors with the command `DensityPlot3D[
 Re[new[\[Alpha], \[Chi], \[Tau]] - old[\[Tau]]], {\[Chi], 
  0, \[Pi]}, {\[Alpha], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Tau], 0.1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 11, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]`. Attaching the picture in the chat for this thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42873/discussion-between-junaid-aftab-and-feyre).

Answer (score 0):

The command given before editing the question and before my answer was:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[new[α_, χ_, τ_] - old[τ_], {α, 0, 2 π}, {χ, 0, π}], {τ, 0, 1}]
```

My answer is:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[new[τ, α, χ]] - Evaluate[old[τ]], {α, 0, 2 π}, {χ,0, π}], {τ, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Edited. Check the code. I get a similar error. See the edited post.

Comment: What is w? I haven't defined it.

Comment: Why are you taking omega to be between 0 and 70? I am already numerically integrating over it and it is no longer a variable that appears in my function in the Plot command.

Comment: I do the calculation with \[Omega] from 0 to 70 just for getting lower time of calculation. In your code is from 0 to 70000

Comment: That's a big no. I have to integrate over a large value of omega. Since Mathematica is bad at handling infinity (in most cases), I put in a 70,000. 70 is too low!

Comment: You should get the results for \[Omega] from 0 to 70000 with adding Evaluate to the functions. This answer to you question.

Comment: I don't. Check the code I edited a few minutes ago.

Comment: I get the `Aborted` as the output.

Comment: I added the result for \[Omega]=0 to 70000

Comment: What about the Manipulate command? That lets me slide across various values `\[Tau]` between 0 and 2 -- and get a graph for each different value of `\[Tau].` I think that's what resulting in the error in my case: `Aborted.` Computationally heavy!

Comment: You should not edit and change the question after the answer is given ?!

Comment: From the question know, my answer has no sense ?

Comment: That command was already in there; also, it's an ongoing discussion and I haven't accepted an answer. It seems as if my problem is computationally very hard for Mathematica to handle.

Comment: Your command was wrong:Manipulate[
 Plot3D[new[\[Alpha]_, \[Chi]_, \[Tau]_]- 
  old[\[Tau]], {\[Alpha], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {\[Chi], 
   0, \[Pi]}], {\[Tau]_, 0, 1}]

Comment: That's what I said: I had used the Manipulate command.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful